# iframe not scrolling on mobile device

Tags: html, css, iframe

The thing is that I am making a temporary page for my brother's site. The page just has a google order form embedded in it and social media links displayed on top. The form has to cover entire screen. This is the site http://whygenapparel.com/order.html. The problem occurring is that it's working perfectly fine on desktop, but the `<iframe>` is not scrolling on mobile(iPhone 6 in my case). I have tried everything. Please help.
This is my HTML code.

```
    <div class="social-media-buttons">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/WhyGenApparel/?fref=ts"                                                                target="_blank"> <img src="images/fb-white-25-by-25.png"></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/WhyGenApparel" target="_blank"><img src="images/twitter-white-25-by-25.png"></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/whygenapparel/" target="_blank"><img src="images/insta-white-25-by-25.png"></a>
</div>
<div class="order-form" style="overflow:auto;-webkit-overflow-scrolling:touch">
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1iqlMn-UGnKPN06WFbkGlj6cPAEGjK1341gKfo4eLst4/viewform" style="position:fixed; top:0px; left:0px; bottom:0px; right:0px; width:100%; height:100%; border:none; margin:0; padding:0; overflow:hidden; z-index:-1"></iframe>
</div>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
.social-media-buttons{ margin-top:5px;}
.order-form{ display:block; clear:both;}
```

Comment: I just tried it using http://ipadpeek.com/ and it works fine there!

Comment: It was even working on android but not on iPhone. I changed "position:fixed" to "position:absolute" and now it works for iPhone as well.